# Where do the names value/expression kept in functional programs?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, erlang

In C#, all the value fields like int, float are kept in stack and all the reference variables pointers are in stack and the actual values are kept in heap. (hope my understanding is correct here). 
 
1. Since in functional programming model there is no value and reference type, where do the name symbol values are kept?
2.How does the stack and heap come into play on functional programs? 
Thanks

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in the C# language specification which says anything about where values are stored. In fact, it doesn't even mention stack and heap at all. It's perfectly valid to implement C# completely without a stack and allocate everything on the heap. Or with a dynamically resizeable stack and no heap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since functional languages generally use immutable values (meaning: "variables" that you can't modify), it doesn't matter for the user whether the values are stored on the stack or on the heap.

Because of this, typically the compiler will decide how to store the values. For example, it might decide that small values (integers, floats, pairs of integers, 8 byte arrays, etc) are stored on the stack and large values (strings, lists, ...) are stored on the heap. It is fully the compiler's decision.

For languages like Haskell, that supports lazy evaluation, values need to be stored on the heap (except when some tricks are used). This is because a variable needs to either be a pointer to the function/closure that computes the value, or a pointer to the actual already computed value.

Comment: That "except when some tricks are used" is hiding a lot of very effective tricks. The worker-wrapper transformation used for unboxing, list fusion, stream fusion, and known-constructor specialization can have some pretty impressive results. The data structure you've used may not actually exist by the time the compiler is through with it.

Comment: Do functional languages generally use immutable values?  Lisp doesn't.  ML doesn't (although practitioners wish it did, and try to pretend).   I think it's a rare generalization of functional languages that doesn't include at least one of those families.

Comment: @JohnL: the definition of "functional language" has changed over the years. It used to mean "language with first-class procedures", but since pretty much *every* language except C now has first-class procedures, that is a meaningless distinction. It is now more commonly being used to mean "language with (mathematical) functions", and thus excludes Lisp, for example. (Note that e.g. Guy Steele never uses the term "function" when talking about Scheme, he always says "procedure", the Scheme spec calls it an "algorithmic language" and Common Lisp is usually termed "multi-paradigm".)

Comment: @JohnL: William Cook wrote a humorous article about "the day functional programming became pure" where he traces this shift of meaning in the edit history of the Wikipedia article about functional programming: http://wcook.blogspot.de/2012/07/day-functional-programming-changed.html

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I am not quite sure what you mean, but you can't seriously be arguing that mathematical functions are non-existent in Lisp?  However, if we take "functional language" to mean a language that encourages the avoidance of state and mutable data (I'm not 100% willing to grant this is *the* definition, but I happily admit it's a reasonable definition), then I guess it's tautological that such a language would use immutable values.

Comment: @JohnL to clarify, I used "functional" with the mathematical definition. Lisp and ML are not purely functional languages; they are mostly functional, but mutable variables are a procedural concept.

Answer (score 17):

You're trying to compare C#, which is one specific language, with *functional languages* all as a group.  This is an apples-to-oranges comparison (or maybe more accurately, apples-to-spices comparison?).

Within imperative languages already you can observe differences between what values are stored in the stack vs. which ones go on the heap.  For example, C and C++ (as I understand it) allow the programmer to manually choose which of these two ways they want for any type.

And another subtlety is the difference between what the language *guarantees* to the programmer vs. the way the language is *implemented*.  One example is that recent versions of Oracle's Java VM have an optimization that they call ["escape analysis"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis), which is able to allocate an object on the stack if the VM can prove that the object reference does not escape the method (determined after inlining is performed).  So even though Java calls its object types "reference" types, this doesn't mean that it will be allocated in the heap.  Quoting [this article by Brian Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html):

> The Java language does not offer any way to explicitly allocate an object on the stack, but this fact doesn't prevent JVMs from still using stack allocation where appropriate. JVMs can use a technique called *escape analysis*, by which they can tell that certain objects remain confined to a single thread for their entire lifetime, and that lifetime is bounded by the lifetime of a given stack frame. Such objects can be safely allocated on the stack instead of the heap. Even better, for small objects, the JVM can optimize away the allocation entirely and simply hoist the object's fields into registers.

Similar considerations apply to functional languages—it all depends on (a) what does the language promise, and (b) how the language implementation works and how sophisticated it is.  But we can divide the functional language world into two important camps:

1. *Eager* functional languages like Scheme, Scala, Clojure or ML.
2. *Lazy* functional languages like Haskell.

There are several types of implementation for eager languages:

1. Pure stack-based implementations.  These work same way as modern imperative languages.  Common Lisp works this way.  Since JVM functional languages use the same VM as Java does, so do they.
2. Pure continuation-passing style implementations.  These are completely stackless—everything, including activation frames, is allocated on the heap.  These make it easy to support [tail-call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and [first-class continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation#First-class_continuations).  This technique I believe was pioneered by Scheme implementations, and is also used by the Standard ML of New Jersey compiler.
3. Mixed implementations.  These typically are trying to be mostly stack-based but also support tail-call optimization, and maybe first-class continuations.  Example: a bunch of random Scheme systems.

Lazy languages are another story, because the conventional call-stack implementation does not translate directly to lazy evaluation.  [The GHC Haskell compiler is based on a model called the "STG Machine"](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/GeneratedCode), which does use a stack and a heap, but the way the STG stack works is different from imperative languages; an entry in the STG stack does not correspond to a "function call" as conventional stack entries do.

Answer (score 1):

Since Scala is mentioned in the tags, I'll add and answer about that language. Scala compiles to JVM bytecode, so, at the end of the day, it works just like any other JVM language (including Java):

- references and locally defined primitives go on the stack;
- objects (including their primitive fields) go on the heap.

About primitive types, it's worth noting that Scala doesn't actually have primitive types in the language; but value types (like Int or Long) do get compiled to the JVM's primitive types in the bytecode, when possible.

edit: To avoid leaving somethign incorrect in this answer: as mentioned in Luis Casillas' extensive answer, objects may end up stored on the stack (or even not allocated as objects at all) if the JVM can judge that it's safe and efficient to do so.